# Face recognition pre processing

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, face-recognition

I'm working on a face recognition project. In order to improve the accuracy of the algorithm, we tried to do some preprocessing, following this article:

http://lear.inrialpes.fr/pubs/2007/TT07/Tan-amfg07a.pdf

Based on that, we made the following code:

```
def dif_gaussian(img, sigma0 = 1.0, sigma1 = 2.0):
    blur1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(0,0),sigma0)
    blur2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(0,0),sigma1)
    result = cv2.subtract(blur1,blur2)
    return np.uint8(result)

def gamma_correction(img, correction):
    temp = img/255.0
    result = cv2.pow(temp, correction)
    return np.uint8(result*255)



predict_image_pil = Image.open('image.jpg').convert('L')
predict_image = np.array(predict_image_pil, 'uint8')

predict_gamma = gamma_correction(predict_image,0.2)

predict_gauss = dif_gaussian(predict_gamma,1.0,2.0)

predict_hist = cv2.equalizeHist(predict_gauss)
```

But our resulting image, especially on the Difference of Gaussian part, is way different from the images showed on the article. Is there any mistake on the processing that I`m not seeing?

Comment: Can you add more details of how you are saving/viewing the resulting image(s)?

Comment: I'm using cv2.imshow to see the image through each step. For now I'm just running the preprocessing and trying to get a similar result comparing to the article. The images aren't being saved.

Comment: look e.g. here: https://github.com/bytefish/facerec/blob/master/py/facerec/preprocessing.py#L44 - i think, you're missing the pow() and tanh() steps at the end. and then, imho you should just normalize() the result, not do another histogram-equalization

Comment: i followed the whole procedure used on bytefish`s Github, and I got this result:

https://imageshack.com/i/exzFwVWKj

It's really far from the expected result...

Comment: Hi @LincolnAlves , did you solved your issue. I am using face recognition library which is working fine but I think I can improve accuracy using pre processing methods so just curious if you were able to do it.?

Comment: Hey @SAndrew ! Unfortunately, I was working in this project during an exchange student program and I had to leave before the project was completed. We've ended up with the following code https://codeshare.io/5woEVJ
...Fun fact: the guy who was working with me on the project was also called Andrew hahah

Comment: @LincolnAlves Did this improved your face recognition accuracy.?

Comment: @SAndrew I believe this script resulted in a fairly good accuracy at the time! It's been a long time since this was made, so there's probably better ways to achieve a good accuracy now.